# What kind of transformation should I use for this ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am looking at the following ODE:

$\frac{1}{2}{\sigma ^2}{y^2}\frac{{{d^2}}}{{d{y^2}}}\left( {g(y)} \right) + ry\frac{d}{{dy}}\left( {g(y)} \right) - rg(y) + c = 0$

It seems obvious to me that a simple transformation could eliminate the y and give me an ODE with constant coefficients. Any idea what I should be trying?

Comment: What is $r$ and $\sigma$ ? Are they independent of $y$, or  functions of $y$, or constants  ?

Answer (score 0):

For the solution of the equation
$$\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2y^2g''(y)+ryg'(y)-rg(y)=0$$ make the ansatz $$g(y)=y^{\lambda}$$ then we get $$\lambda=1$$ or $$\lambda=-\frac{2r}{\sigma^2}$$ and the particular solution is given by $$g_p(y)=\frac{c}{r}$$